# sumif in SQL from split columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a DateTime column and I use

```
select 
convert(date,DateTime) as activity_date,
convert(varchar(8), convert(time,DateTime)) as activity_time,
from table
```

and I get these value

```
activity_date activity_time Value
02-22-22      10:00:00      2
02-22-22      11:00:00      10
02-22-23      10:00:00      8
02-22-23      11:00:00      6
```

Now I want

```
activity_hour  Value
10:00:00       10
11:00:00       16
```

How can I sum the new column value?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you just need an aggregation query here:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(time, DateTime) AS activity_time, SUM(Value) AS Value
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY CONVERT(time, DateTime)
ORDER BY CONVERT(time, DateTime);
```

Comment: When I combine everything

Select 
convert(date,DateTime) as activity_date,
convert(varchar(8), convert(time,DateTime)) as activity_time,
sum(value) as value
from table
group by activity_time

SQL keeps saying that there is no activity_time column (sorry I am on my phone so I can't have good format)

Comment: @cherryberry, you cannot use a column alias in the GROUP BY. You need to use the expression `GROUP BY convert(date,DateTime) , convert(varchar(8), convert(time,DateTime)) `